# Relationships in laravel 5.4 ond display data

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have two tables and I want to display all the fields where :`question_id.Question = question_id.QuestionOption`. I don't know how do it in Laravel:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('question_text');
    $table->integer('points');
    $table->integer('temps_reponse');

    $table->integer('categories_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('categories_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

    $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');

    $table->timestamps();

});

Schema::create('question_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('option_one');
    $table->string('option_two');
    $table->string('option_three');
    $table->string('correcte');

    $table->integer('question_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions');

    $table->timestamps();

});
```

my foreach loop but dosn't works :

```
@foreach ($question_options as $question_option)
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $question_option->question->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $question_option->question->question_text }}</td>
            <td>{{ $question_option->option_one }}</td>
            <td>{{ $question_option->option_two }}</td>
            <td>{{ $question_option->option_three }}</td>
            <td>{{ $question_option->question->points }}</td>                                 
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define relations in your models:

**Question model:**

```php
class Question extends Model {
    public $table = 'questions';

    public function options() {
        return $this->hasMany(QuestionOption::class);
    }
}
```

**QuestionOption model:**

```php
class QuestionOption extends Model {
    public $table = 'questions_options';

    public function question() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
}
```

From now you can access options question options:

`$question = Question::with('options')->first();`

and in your view:

```php
@foreach($question->options as $question_option)
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $question_option->question->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $question_option->question->question_text }}</td>
            <td>{{ $question_option->option_one }}</td>
            <td>{{ $question_option->option_two }}</td>
            <td>{{ $question_option->option_three }}</td>
            <td>{{ $question_option->question->points }}</td>                                 
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
@endforeach
```

Instead of `$question_option->question->question_text` you can access `question_text` directly from `$question` object.

Comment: Thank you for answer it was helpful but when I want to replace first with get to retrieve all rows it show me this error ```Property [options] does not exist on this collection instance.```because with first i have just one row